# Efficient Cartesian product algo Pandas DFs / partial match between columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, vectorization

I have two dataframes

df1

```
name
xyz limited
abc private
lmn limited
pqrlimited
abc def xyz limited
abc private limited
```

df2

```
flag   tag
E    private
A    limited
```

And the desired output is

Output :

```
name         flag   tag
xyz limited   A    limited
abc private   E    private
lmn limited   A    limited 
pqrlimited    A    limited 
abc def xyz limited    A    limited
abc private limited    A    limited
abc private limited    E    private
```

My code:

```
df1['tmp'] = 1
df2['tmp'] = 1

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['tmp'])                     
df3 = df3.drop('tmp',axis=1)

df3 = df3[df3.apply(lambda x: x['tag'] in (x['name']), axis=1)]
```

But in reality both dataframes contain millions of records. Can someone pls suggest the most efficient way to works this out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` with `merge`:

```
df1['tag'] = df1['name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)[1]
df1.merge(df2)
#or
df1['flag'] = df1['tag'].map(df2.set_index('tag')['flag'])
#or if the strings not seperated then
df1['tag'] = df1['name'].str.findall('|'.join(set(df2['tag'].tolist()))).str[0]
```

Updated Solution:

```
df1 = (df1.reset_index()
          .merge(df1.name.str.findall('|'.join(set(df2['tag'].tolist()))).explode().reset_index(name='tag'), 
                on='index')
          .drop('index', axis=1))
df=df1.merge(df2)
```

Comment: Thank you! But, i do have some records like 'pqrlimited' with no separator.. how do we resolve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
regx = '|'.join(df2['tag'])
df1['tag'] = df1['name'].str.extract(f'({regx})')
df1['flag'] = df1['tag'].map(df2.set_index('tag')['flag'])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
                  name      tag flag
0          xyz limited  limited    A
1          abc private  private    E
2          lmn limited  limited    A
3           pqrlimited  limited    A
4  abc def xyz limited  limited    A
5  abc private limited  private    E
```

#### Details:

- Create a regular expression with a list of tags found in df2
- Extract those tags from df1 name column
- Map those tags to the flag value in df2